# $X\in L^2$ implies $Y:=(X-E[X])^2 \in L^1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given the random variable $X \in L^2$, we define a new variable $Y:=(X-E[X])^2$, where $E$ is the expectation. Why can we conclude that $Y\in L^1$?

Is it because for any function $f \in L^2$ the norm is $(\int_X|f|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, so the norm squared would be a new function $g \in L^2$ with $(\int_X|g|)$?

Comment: Just expand that square and use that if $Y \in L^2$ then $Y \in L^1$ (this is true on probability spaces, using Holder's inequality). (You'll also use that the sum of $L^1$ functions is$L^1$)

Comment: By definition, $X$ is square integrable if its square is integrable, hence so is $Y.$ (I am not sure if you are asking for this tautology or something else...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E|Y| = E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 \le E[X^2] < \infty.$$

Comment: How do you actually get$E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$?

Comment: @Thesinus $E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[X^2 - 2 X E[X] + (E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - 2 (E[X])^2 + (E[X])^2$.

Comment: To Thesinus:
Just as what @angryavian stated above. Plus, if you are still curious on how it works, you can expand expected value into its Lebesgue integral expression, then applying the properties of Lebesgue integral ($\sigma$-additive, etc), and you'll get just as it is.